SearchBar widget color remains another color after it set to the transparent in flutter
after setting up the background color of the searchBar wdget, it still remains with a lighter blue color within it.When another color is set, it apply those colors as well.Then creates a awful color
see the image here
In above image ,
The above search bar is the one with problem.The below one is custom input field**.See the color difference even though both set to the Colors.transparent **
              SearchBar(
              hintText: "Search",
              // hintStyle: MaterialStateProperty<TextStyle>(col),
              side: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                  const BorderSide(color: Colors.black45)),
              shadowColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
              overlayColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
              // controller: controller,
              padding: const MaterialStatePropertyAll<EdgeInsets>(
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)),
              shape: const MaterialStatePropertyAll<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)))),
              onTap: () {
                // controller.openView();
              },
              onChanged: (e) {
                print(e);
                // searchProducts(e);
                setState(() {
                  _productList = searchProducts(e);
                });
                // controller.openView();
              },
              leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
              // trailing: <Widget>[
              //   Tooltip(
              //     message: 'Change brightness mode',
              //     child: IconButton(
              //       // isSelected: isDark,
              //       onPressed: () {
              //         setState(() {
              //           // isDark = !isDark;
              //         });
              //       },
              //       icon: const Icon(Icons.wb_sunny_outlined),
              //       selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.brightness_2_outlined),
              //     ),
              //   )
              // ],
            ),

how to control color without this automatic color and set it to the desired color as required

You are seeing a tint in the SearchBar. Use the surfaceTintColor property to  remove the tint.
      child: SearchBar(
        hintText: "Search",
        // hintStyle: MaterialStateProperty<TextStyle>(col),
        side: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
            const BorderSide(color: Colors.black45)),
        shadowColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
        overlayColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),
        surfaceTintColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.transparent),....

Now updating the backgroundColor will use the desired color without tint. See the details of surfaceTintColor from flutter documentation.
  /// If null, the value of [SearchBarThemeData.surfaceTintColor] will be used.
  /// If this is also null, then the default value is [ColorScheme.surfaceTint].
  final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? surfaceTintColor;


Yeah.It worked.Thanks man!
